# LIke button behavior

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'd like to offer customers on my site a 5% discount on their order if they tell  their friends about my site by clicking the site's Like button.

My first question is, Would Facebook have any objection to me using the Like button like this?

Second, I notice that if you return to a site that you've already Liked,  the Like button is not enabled, so you can't Like the site again. Is the memory of the previous Like stored in a cookie on the user's browser or is there some central database that FB maintains?  If it's a browser cookie my plans could get expensive it users keep clearing their cookies and getting the discount every time they visit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is data that FB maintains.  I don't see why FB would have any objections to using the Like button in that way but you may just want to read over their TOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check to see if a user is a fan or not (likes), then look up "fan-gate".  It is a design that allows you to show content only for people who have liked.

I am pretty sure it's OK to use the like button in this matter (offering 5% discount), however I'm not an attorney.  Have your company's attorney check out Platform Policies at https://developers.facebook.com/policy